# SharePoint 2019 expand lookup of lookup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, 2019

I am using SharePoint 2019. I have list as below structure:

### Department

- ID
- Title

### Process

- ID
- Title
- Department (lookup to department)

### BIA

- ID
- Title
- Process (lookup to process)

Now my question is when I REST query to **BIA** I expand Process list, is it possible to expand Department in the same REST API call?

Comment: Hope somebody will reply

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible using a single REST API call.

You will need two API calls. 1st call to expand the details of Process list & 2nd call to expand the details of department list.

Comment: Than this will be very heavy, as I have to call for each row

Comment: I am not sure about your other code setup. But, this is a limitation of SharePoint REST API, you cannot expand 2nd level lookup columns.

Comment: Do you know any better way !! I am using pnpjs

Comment: Can you please ask a separate question for this? What exactly you are trying to do? what do you mean by "I have to call for each row"? maybe there is alternate way to achieve what you want. Also, add the current code you are using to your new question.

Comment: I am trying to show all items in table like BIA-->Title, Process-->Title, and Department-->Title as I cannot do expand department and I have to call api for each department

Comment: In that case, maybe you can first fetch all the department & process list items and then match it with BIA list item using client side scripting & loops.